# How to validate a string contains only some special characters is allowed in Java?

Tags: java, android

I want  to validate a string in Java. It should not allow any special characters, exclude @._ at dot underscore . Only this 3 characters should allow. No space is allowed. And Only English alphabets allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex (Regular Expressions):

```
public static boolean isValid(String s) {
  return s.matches("[a-zA-Z@._]*");
}
```

**Explanation**:

- `[a-zA-Z@._]`: Matches a single character that is either in the English alphabet, or the three special characters '@', '.' and '_'.
- `*`: Matches the previous expression between zero and unlimited times.

**Note**:

If empty strings are not valid either, use `[a-zA-Z@._]+` as the regex instead, or additionally test whether `s.isEmpty()` or has length of 0.

Comment: This is working fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it through Regex Expressions and its pretty simple. It will allow all Numeric and Alphabets and allow only **@**,**.**,**"_"**

```
public static boolean isValidString(String s) {
      return s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9@._]*");
    }
```

input :"imranishaq$123"
Output: false

input :"imranishaq#123"
Output: false

input :"imranishaq@123"
Output: true

input :"imranishaq.123"
Output: true

input :"imranishaq_123"
Output: true